# Dock is not working anymore

Tags: macos, dock

All of a sudden some running applications were not shown on the <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇥</kbd> on-screen list. I had to restart my MBP, running Yosemite 10.10.2.

After restarting, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇥</kbd> was not working any more (no app shown on screen, not even the Finder) and the Dock showed some non-running apps as running (with the circle). By clicking any 'running' app the circle disappeared.

So I opened Terminal and run `killall Dock`.

- The Dock did not restart.
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇥</kbd> is still not working.
- Restart does not work.
- Shut-down does not work.
- Spotlight works and I can launch apps.

No apps were installed between the normal, working stage and this absurd state.

What's the problem? Any suggestion?

Answer (score -1):

Try re-applying the 10.10.2 update, or download and install the 10.10.3 combo update and see if that fixes it.
Here's the link to the combo updater:

https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1804?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Comment: Google 'Yosemite 10.10.3 combo' & use that rather than the regular delta update. On phone so no link to hand.